# FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND info logs after kafka-clients upgrade

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka cluster with `1.1.1` version. I recently upgraded the `kafka-clients` in the consumer application to `1.1.1` version and after the upgrade,  I could see the below info logs `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` . If I use the older `kafka-clients` version `0.11.0.2`, I don't see any such logs.

Why am I getting `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` logs?

The log:

```
[INFO ] 2019-10-11 17:20:44.284 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] FetchSessionHandler - [Consumer clientId=consumer-4, groupId=*] Node 1190181239 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=265690453, epoch=518): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND.
```